# Incorrect time showing on marketing Cloud emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, datetime

I am sending out emails from the Marketing cloud. The email template uses AMPScript from a Date time field in Salesforce. I only need to capture the Date part of the field, however, since the clocks have been moved forward this no longer works. Is this working as designed or is there a better way to manage the time stamp.

```
Var @CBDateTime, @CBDateString, @CBTimeString

  Set @CBDateTime = [Field in Salesforce]

  Set @CBDateTime = SystemDateToLocalDate(@CBDateTime)

  Set @CBDateString = Formatdate(@CBDateTime, "d MMMM yyyy","","en-GB")

  Set @CBkTimeString = Formatdate(@CBDateTime, "hh:00 tt","","en-GB")
```

This then displays as **08:00 AM** and not 09:00 AM as per the field in Salesforce which contains **09/04/2018 09:00**

Answer (score 1):

It may be the "SystemDateToLocalDate", as that converts it to the user's time. For example, when I used that "SystemDateToLocalDate" 9AM in the Salesforce field converted to 11AM in the test email. This doesn't happen when I do not include "SystemDateToLocalDate". Below are some screenshots. Hope this helps!

[image: Data Extension]

[image: AMPScript][image: final email preview]

Comment: Thank you for the reply, although not fixed this did lead to a bit of a breakthrough. I was able to remove the local date and I was returned the same result. I then confirmed the 'raw' values in the SalesCloud and realised my time zone was not the same as the system (Mine was GMT+1 and System is GMT). It looks like the SalesCloud that the value comes from is storing the value -1hr as GMT (not GMT+1 for the summer). I need to add an hour to the value or find out why my SalesCloud is passing over GMT values to Marketing Cloud any ideas?

Comment: hmmm. Well, our Marketing Cloud has it's own system timezone. And, I believe, can be set differently than SalesForce. I would check the Admin settings in MC (and SF) to see if there are differences in both to be sure.

Comment: I changed all of the time zones to the same and this didnt work so ive gone with the following to add an hour as they are from 9am - 8 pm uk region only. this is until i can find a long term solution. for now I need clients to see the right times in the emails:
%%=v(Formatdate(DateAdd(@CBTimeString, '1','h'), "","HH:mm","en-GB"))=%%

Comment: From what I understand, imported dates from Salesforce CRM are automatically converted to Salesforce Marketing Cloud system time (CST) in the Data Extension.  This might help in your investigation.